# Invalid CSRF when logging in to keystone

Tags: keystonejs

I'm entirely new to coding. I've looked around a bit, but not found anything relevant.

When logging into **keystone** to view our **mongoDB** database I get an error message saying:

> Something went wrong; please refresh your browser and try again.

Doing that does not help. Neither does deleting the browser history or attempting from another lap top.

Looking at the javascript console in the browser, the error states `invalid csrf`.

I think this is the relevant source code in the **keystone** folder:

```
handleSubmit (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // If either password or mail are missing, show an error
        if (!this.state.email || !this.state.password) {
            return this.displayError('Please enter an email address and password to sign in.');
        }

        xhr({
            url: `${Keystone.adminPath}/api/session/signin`,
            method: 'post',
            json: {
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password,
            },
            headers: assign({}, Keystone.csrf.header),
        }, (err, resp, body) => {
            if (err || body && body.error) {
                return body.error === 'invalid csrf'
                    ? this.displayError('Something went wrong; please refresh your browser and try again.')
                    : this.displayError('The email and password you entered are not valid.');
            } else {
                // Redirect to where we came from or to the default admin path
                if (Keystone.redirect) {
                    top.location.href = Keystone.redirect;
                } else {
                    top.location.href = this.props.from ? this.props.from : Keystone.adminPath;
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

How can I go about solving this / debugging the error? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when session affinity fails. Are you using default in-memory session management? Maybe, try using a database for maintaining session state.

If you use MongoDB, Try the following config setting

```
'session store': 'mongo',
```

See 'session store' section under http://keystonejs.com/docs/configuration/#options-database for more details.